# Vertical alignment of UIBarButtonItem is problematic on iPad

Tags: ios, uibarbuttonitem, uitoolbar, nsattributedstring

I'm using a custom `UIView` as the `titleView` in a `UINavigationBar`. The `UIView`'s only subview is a `UIToolbar` to which I've added two `UIBarButtonItem`s. One contains an image (the twitter icon in the screenshot below) and the other contains title text.

On iPhone, this all looks great, but on iPad (using the same xib files and code) the vertical alignment is off. Here it is on iPhone:

[image: Custom iPhone title view]

And here it is on iPad (notice that the twitter icon isn't vertically aligned with the text in other button item):
[image]

The code I'm using to set the title is:

```
NSDictionary *textAttributes =  @{NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont systemFontOfSize:17.f],
         NSForegroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor whiteColor]};
[self.caseIdButtonItem setTitleTextAttributes:textAttributes
                                     forState:UIControlStateNormal];
self.caseIdButtonItem.title = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", NSLocalizedString(@"Case #", nil), self.caseId];
```

The above lines get called in my view controller's `viewDidLoad`.

How can I ensure that the bar button items are all aligned vertically in my `UIToolbar`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix this by explicitly setting the `UIView`'s frame height to 44.

Comment: Accept your own answer?